# What scopes and permissions do I need to be able to get someone to download files from my Google Drive?

Tags: python, google-api, permissions, google-drive-api

I provide my credentials along with a python script to allow downloading some files from my Google Drive. I tried using these scopes but they all fail:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly

Only this one worked:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

But this token is asking the user to give read, write, edit, access to Google Drive. Why do they need to have all of these permissions, just to be able to download files from another Google Drive i.e. mine?

I can't find the minimum scope that I need for this operation.

I am using the Google Drive API in python.

Comment: In the case of download the file and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` can be used, how about using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`? The official document says `Allows read-only access to file metadata and file content.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth)

Comment: Thanks yesterday I figured it out https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly indeed worked. You can reply for this so I can mark it as answer if you want.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I thought that your question and solution will be useful for other users. From your proposal and this, I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: This does not work anymore since drive.readonly requires 3rd party assessment... Is there a permission to *download* the current presentation only, in pptx format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question, it was found that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` can be used. From this situation, as the scope for downloading the file, I think that the following scope can be used.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
```

[The official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) says about this scope as follows.

> Allows read-only access to file metadata and file content.

Comment: Does not work anymore.... Is there a way to download the presentation programmatically or alternatively get a permission to download ONLY the current presentation?

Comment: @Nathan B About your question of `Is there a way to download the presentation programmatically or alternatively get a permission to download ONLY the current presentation?`, I would like to support you. But, I cannot understand `Does not work anymore....`. So, can you post it as a new question by including your current script and the details of your current issue? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?